# ¿Cómo imprimir una lista en columnas tabuladas en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Por ejemplo:

```
lista = ['predo','juan','victor','jose','maria','fernanda','oscar','octvio']
```

**Salida:**

```
pedro    fernanda
juan     oscar
victor   octavio
jose
maria
```

Comment: intenta demostrar tu interes y muestranos que has intentado.

Answer (score 5):

Haciendo un poco de "magia avanzada", se puede escribir con pocas líneas.

La idea es, dado el número deseado de filas en tu tabla (serían 5 en tu ejemplo), dividir la lista original en grupos de 5 elementos, rellenando con espacios si no hay suficiente. Así en tu caso saldrían dos grupos:

```
['predo','juan','victor','jose','maria']
['fernanda','oscar','octvio', '', '']
```

Esta división por grupos la haría una función que llamaré `grouper()` y que he copiado de un ejemplo que aparece en [la documentación del módulo itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), en la documentación oficial de Python. Sería así:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=""):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Explicar cómo y por qué funciona sería muy prolijo. Pero baste saber que hace lo descrito antes si la invocas con `grouper(lista, 5)`.

Ahora, se unen los grupos resultantes con la función estándar `zip()`. Esta función va emparejando elementos de un grupo con los del grupo siguiente, etc. Así se formarían las parejas `('predo', 'fernanda')`, `('juan', 'oscar')`, etc.

Finalmente cada una de esas parejas (o quizás sean trios, o grupos de N en general, si la lista inicial tiene muchos elementos), se juntan en una línea con ayuda de `"".join()`, formateando cada uno de los nombres usando una cadena de formato que fuerce a que todos ellos usen el mismo ancho (por ejemplo 10 ó 15 caracteres). Esto rellenará con espacios cuando sea necesario, obteniendo así la alineación en vertical. El número elegido debe ser mayor que la longitud del nombre más largo.

El código completo sería como sigue, en el cual, para que sea más flexible, permito que pases como parámetro el número de filas deseadas y el ancho en caracteres de las columnas:

```
def print_en_columnas(lista, numfilas, ancho=15):
  for fila in zip(*grouper(lista, numfilas)):
    print("".join(f"{nombre:{ancho}s}" for nombre in fila))
```

Ejemplos de uso, dada tu lista:

```
>>> print_en_columnas(lista, numfilas=5, ancho=10)
predo     fernanda  
juan      oscar     
victor    octvio    
jose                
maria    

>>> print_en_columnas(lista, numfilas=3, ancho=10)
predo     jose      oscar     
juan      maria     octvio    
victor    fernanda       

>>> print_en_columnas(lista, numfilas=3, ancho=15)
predo          jose           oscar          
juan           maria          octvio         
victor         fernanda
```

Comment: eres un mago amigo!!!